# Why is the scrollheight of my React component in an iframe 150px?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe

I have an AngularJS website and a React App run on the same domain. I'm trying to run the React component through an iframe to display on one of the web pages of the website.
I have the component displaying but I am trying to make the height of the iframe equal to the height of the content so that there is no need for a scrollbar. I have tried loads of solutions and it seems like using `document.getElementById('my-iframe').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight` is the right way to go however this is always 150px when I console log when setting the iframe height.

I have a `setTimeout` so that I wait until the iframe content is fully loaded but even then the height is logged as 150px. I know the content is much more than this because the scrollbar appears with the iframe instead of displaying it in full height.

I know the iframe default height is 150px but the content is larger than this - any ideas as to how I can access the true height of the React component content from the website?

Answer (score 0):

The `iframe` HTML element has the default height; [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-height).

To update the default height, you need to pass `height` attribute as below.

```
<iframe id="iframe-abc" height="100%" src="abc.com"/>
<iframe id="iframe-abc" height="400px" src="abc.com"/>
```